# JS Audio autoplay

Tags: javascript, аудио

Пишу игру на JS. Хочу добавить несколько аудио элементов для фонового воспроизведения. как обойти блокировку браузеров на автовоспроизведение?

Comment: Повесьте на кнопку "Начать игру" `audio.play()`, никакой проблемы нет. Не надо обходить то, что сделано ради безопасности и комфорта пользователей. Все обходные маневры со временем будут включаться в алгоритмы запрета автовоспроизведения.

Answer (score 1):

Я так добавлял:

```
function playSound(signal){
    if (sound =='on'){
        let audio = document.createElement('audio');
        audio.setAttribute("autoplay","true");
        audio.innerHTML = `<source src="sounds/${signal}.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">`;
        document.body.appendChild(audio);
    }
}
```

Comment: Как-то не стабильно работает)))

Comment: @Leonid, потому что не указано, когда должна запускаться функция `playSound`

Comment: @Grundy, когда она должна вызываться? Я попробовал просто добавить вызов и все. Через Live Server открываю в Хроме и то включается при загрузке, то нет. Потом и вовсе всегда нет. Понятно, что если вызывать ее как результат какого-то действия пользователя, то должно работать. Но тогда и в такой оболочке не будет смысла. А вообще проблема надуманная, по-моему...

Comment: @Leonid [Autoplay availability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#autoplay_availability)

Comment: @Grundy, ничего нового там не прочитал))) Лучшее - привязать к какому-либо пользовательскому действию явного характера, не скролл, например.

Comment: @Leonid, суть как раз в том, как браузер определяет было ли взаимодействие пользователя со страницей, чтобы решить, запускать аудио/видео или нет

Comment: Думаю, не всякое взаимодействие, а именно то, которое можно расценить как намеренное включение медиа. Именно `click`, нажатие `Space` - характерные операции для этого. Поэтому и говорю, что при таком раскладе нет смысла сложную оболочку создавать. А можно непосредственно повесить на это характерное действие простое `audio.play(); sound = 'on';`)) Никаких противоречий в наших точках зрения не вижу.